# Issue with focusing test field inside material UI autocomplete dropdown

Tags: javascript, material-ui, autocomplete, focus, textfield

I have an UI for search where I have used material ui Autcomplete and textfield inside autocomplete renderInput and also I have few more textfield inside autocomplete option.
The issue is that when i focus on title textfield and try to type a value, the value gets typed on search textfield and not the titlte textfield. In the below image I have typed Test on title textfield but its get focussed in search textfield.

```
<Autocomplete
  options={[]}
  value={searchedName}
  renderInput={params => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      onChange={event => onChange(event.target.value)}
      onKeyDown={handleSearch}
      name="search"
      onFocus={() => setFocus(true)}
      onBlur={() => setFocus(false)}
    />
  )}
  noOptionsText=openSearchDropDown()}
/>

const openSearchDropDown= () => (
  <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="title:">Title:</label>
    <div>
      <TextField onChange={handleTitle} fullWidth variant="standard" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="Summary:">Summary:</label>
    <div>
      <TextField onChange={handleSummary} fullWidth variant="standard" />
    </div>
  </form>
)
```

[image]

Comment: You don't have a `onChange` listener for the Title TextField?

Comment: I have on Change listener for the title as well and I see that on change of search text field has been called when i try to type something on title field and eventlistener of title is not getting called.

Comment: I solved it by adding document.getElementById("title")?.focus() , thanks.